# Is there a way to do numerical 4-fold integral for matlab?

Tags: matlab, integral

My question is that how to do the 4-fold integration. I use to want to do more that 5-fold, but I failed..... so, I decide to go back to a lower level, just 4 fold numerical integration. Please check the code below, there are some parameters and one function.

```
clear all; 
%%% === just some parameters ==============
a=4; 
la1=1/(pi*500^2); la2= la1*5;
p1=25; p2=p1/25;
sgma2=10^(-11);
index=1;
g=2./a;
  syms r u1 u2 u3 u4
  powe= 0 ; 
  seta= 10^powe;
  q=pi.*(la1.*p1.^(2./a)+la2.*p2.^(2./a));
%%% === just some parameters END here ==============  

%%% === Function I want to do 4-fold numerical integration below ===
  yi =   exp(-u3.*(1+2.*...
  (  out1      )./...
  (  (( (u3./u1).^(a./2) + (u3./u2).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).*seta.^(-2./a)))).*...
            exp(-sgma2.*q.^(-a./2).* seta.*u3.^(a./2)./...
    ((( (u3./u1).^(a./2) + (u3./u2).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).^(a./2))  );
```

Ok, As you seen, variables are u1,u2,u3,u4. There will be 4 'nest' integration. The most inside variable is u1, 2nd is u2, 3rd is u3, the most outside is u4. The range of u1 is [0, u2], u2 is [0, u3], u3 is [0, u4], u4=[0, Inf]. This is a numerical integration, this means after 4 level numerical integration, the final output is a real number, not a symbol.

Thank you so much for your time. Thanks.

%%%%%====================================================================== 
The information below is what I've tried.

In another "try-version" of my code, yi is only function of u1, u2. and if I use int 2 times as below,

```
    %%= 1000 means Inf here, 1st int var is u1 and range is[0 u2], 2nd int var is w.r.t u2 and [0, 1000 or Inf]

out2 = double ( int(int(yi,u1,0,u2),u2, 0 ,1000))
```

For the code above, it's working! it gave me a real number. Then I want to try 3 fold, If I do the same thing for 3 fold integration, I failed. So, I change yi to function of u1,u2,u3. and I do code below,

```
out2 = double ( int(int(int(yi,u1,0,u2),u2, 0 ,u3)),u3,0,inf)
```

1st var is u1, range is [0 u2]; 2nd var is u2, the range is [0 u3]; last one is u3, [0 Inf]. error from above code is

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 
Error using sym/double
Too many input arguments.

Error in ref7_equ11n2 (line 117)
out2 = double ( int(int(int(yi,u1,0,u2),u2, 0 ,u3)),u3,0,inf)
```

As you seen, I am not using quad2d, integral3 or other in-built functions. Because I know I will get a 'right' answer for 2 or 3 fold integration. But my target is for 4-fold. that's why I need to do it in 'int' way, step by step. Thank you.

Comment: Your parentheses are misplaced.

Comment: To wit, there should be two closing parentheses together at the end, and only one between `u3` and `u3`.

Comment: What is your actual question? That you get a result for lower orders is irrelevant in most cases to solving higher orders. Try using `vpa` before converting to floating point with `double`. Why do you "need" to do this symbolically as opposed to using a numeric method such as one of those proposed in [your extremely similar previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681213/how-to-do-numerical-multiple-integral-more-than-triple-by-using-matlab-thank).

Comment: Also, you're not likely to get a numeric output (only if `u4` gets cancelled out in simplification somehow) by integrating a function of four variables only three times.

Comment: If you do not use symbols, you may be able to do som kind of loop thing to get the output. Like setting 3 values to constant and loop through the last. I am not sure though.

Comment: my question is how to do 4-fold integration for function yi. I tried vap, it's not working. yes, it is similar, that's why I said I want to go back to lower level, 4-fold. the privious question is not solved. Thanks

Comment: @horchler Dear Horchler, thanks for your help. After I use vpa before double, the result for 3-fold intergration shows up!  Could you let me know why I need vpa before double?  Thank you!

Comment: I can't get it to work with the code you posted in R2014b. `vpa` essentially "forces" the symbolic engine to use numeric quadrature (using variable precision arithmetic) rather then attempting a fully-symbolic solution.